# authentication with session cookie in angular 8

Tags: angular, authentication, session, cookies, backend

For the frst time, when send request to backend "/login" and backend set token in session. the backend send response, cookie is there. But any subsequent request from client is not containing that cookie. How can i solve this issue?
And Why my request not bring cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Little code sample could help. It might be related to using :4200 port on client... Try it with built bundles.